# Bundle product having a uneditable items or a different approach

Tags: product, bundled-product, inventory

What I need:

I have a product which could be said like a 3 month subscription of craft pack. There are 12 craft packs totally. Each month a craft pack should be shipped. The payment should not be recurring. The user has to pay for three packs in advance. A craft pack cannot be sold individually. Each pack should be shipped individually  each month. To manage inventory, each 3-subscription should translate to 3 orders. Eg: if user buys a subscription in september, then it should translate as september pack order, october pack order and november pack order. and shipped in respective months.

How I have organised and tried:

- Subscriptions as bundled product

  - Each craft pack as a simple product bundled inside subscription

I have given the option to ship individually.

Problems I face:

1. Bundle Items give ability to edit through drop down/ multi select box. The packs are already bundled, so the user should not edit it.
2. The each items bundled should have quantity as 1. The user should not change it.

HOW TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM. I am new to magento.
Am I in the right direction. Or is there an alternative to this.

Answer (score 1):

Creating multiple *orders* from one shopping cart will only be possible with heavy modifications of Magento internals, you should consider an alternative approach.

What you can do in Magento:

- create multiple partial invoices from one order, splitting up bundles is possible there
- same for shipments
- allow the inventory to go below zero. I am not sure if this helps you because I don't know what problem related to inventory management you wanted to solve with the separation of orders. Inventory qty in Magento goes down as soon as an order is placed.

Comment: I have already started to customize the quote to order conversion. The hard way suits better for my product. I am stuck out here [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41984/create-order-with-cron-job-with-sku-and-customer-id-given) . I see your reputation would definitely help me out in this case. expecting your help